# How can I do Shallow copy of tree using recursion

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, tree

I'm trying to copy the Tree which one has value, children[], addChild(), map(callback).
Passed all test about addChild() but not on map(callback). I'm using Jest and code is like bellow.

The method 'map' should return the Tree which one has same shape but calculated value in original Tree. And it should Not be the old one but new made one.(shallow copy)

I use Object.assign() to make shallow-copied Tree and executed the callback method on all node. But still not passed on test: `should return an identical tree when the map function is identity (depth 1)`

Please take a look and give an advice. thank you.

**Test File**

```js
  it("should return an identical tree when the map function is identity (depth 2)", function() {
    // this "identity" function returns the same value that was passed in
    var identity = function(value) {
      return value;
    };
    // create a tree with some values
    // depth: 0
    var input = new Tree(1);
    // depth: 1
    input.addChild(2);
    input.addChild(3);
    // depth: 2
    input.children[0].addChild(4);
    input.children[0].addChild(5);
    input.children[1].addChild(6);
    input.children[1].addChild(8);

    var result = input.map(identity);
    // the input and output trees should have identical values
    verifyTree(result, input);
  });

const verifyTree = function(result, expectation) {
  expect(result).toBeInstanceOf(Tree);
  expect(result.value).toEqual(expectation.value);
  expect(result).not.toBe(expectation);
  expect(result.children).toHaveLength(expectation.children.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < result.children.length; i++) {
    verifyTree(result.children[i], expectation.children[i]); // and each child is also verified
  }
};
```

**tree file**

```js
var Tree = function(value) {
  this.value = value;
  this.children = [];
};

Tree.prototype.addChild = function(child) {
  // your code here
  let newChild;

  if(typeof child === 'number'){
    newChild = new Tree(child);
  }else{
    newChild = child
  }

  this.children.push(newChild);
};

Tree.prototype.map = function(callback) {
  let copied = new Tree();
  copied = Object.assign(new Tree(),this);

  // recusion
  function preorder(curNode){
    if(curNode){
      let newValue = curNode.value;
      curNode.value = callback(newValue);
      if(curNode.children){
        for(let i=0 ; i<curNode.children.length ; i++){
          preorder(curNode.children[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  preorder(copied);
  return copied;
};
```

And the error message is like this.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX6KF.png)

Comment: This is a deep copy, isn't it? Not a shallow copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you're having is that "shallow copy" and "recursion" really don't mix.

If you're mapping a tree structure, then you need to to map every node, so that

```
1
+--- 2
|    |
|    +--- 4
|    |
|    +--- 5
|
+--- 3
     |
     +--- 6
     |    |
     |    +--- 7
     |
     +--- 8
```

maps to

```
1
+--- 4
|    |
|    +--- 16
|    |
|    +--- 25
|
+--- 9
     |
     +--- 36
     |    |
     |    +--- 49
     |
     +--- 64
```

This is a *deep* mapping.  However, it's quite easy to accomplish.  This should do the trick:

```js
Tree.prototype.map = function (callback) {
  const newTree = new Tree (callback (this.value))
  newTree .children = (this .children || []) .map (function (child) {
    return child .map (callback)
  })
  return newTree
}
```

This is easy to do because the `children` property is publicly exposed.  If it was buried in a closure and you had to use the `addChild` method for each node, it might look like this:

```js
Tree.prototype.map = function (callback) {
  const newTree = new Tree (callback (this .value));
  (this .children || []) .forEach (function (child) {
      newTree .addChild (child .map (callback))
  })
  return newTree
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am going to answer using a simplified that you can apply to your specific structure.
Say we have a tree that looks like this:

```
[
    [2,56,1],
    [2,7,3],
    [8,4,1]
]
```

And we wanted to make a copy of it we would use this code:

```js
function copy(tree){
    let newTree = [];
    tree.forEach(value => {
        if(Array.isArray(value)){ //Check if the value is a branch
            newTree.push(copy(value)); // Go down the branch
        }else{ //If its not a branch just push the value
            newTree.push(value);
        }
    });
    return newTree;
}
```

The basic algorith I use is this:

```
function copy takes argument Tree
set newTree to empty
for every item in Tree
  If item is branch
    set branch to call copy with argument item 
    append branch to newTree
  else
    append item to newTree
return newTree
```

You should be able to apply this type of algorithm to your tree as well

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. Sorry for late comment.
Both of you guys answers are all helpful for me.
I solved this problem like below.

```js
var Tree = function(value) {
  this.value = value;
  this.children = [];
};

Tree.prototype.addChild = function(child) {
  const newTree = new Tree(child);
  this.children.push(newTree);
};

Tree.prototype.map = function(callback) {
  // your code here
  const newTree = new Tree(callback(this.value));

  (this.children || []).forEach(
    child => newTree.children.push(child.map(callback))
    );

  return newTree;
};
```